# Tiptap extension for images and editable captions

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, prose-mirror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h160.gif)

I want to implement **image and editable caption with tiptap extension**

https://discuss.prosemirror.net/t/figure-and-editable-caption/462
There was a very good example with ProseMirror, but is it difficult to achieve with tiptap?
Please tell me what code you should write if possible.

I attach the code that I wrote below.
The image and caption have been successfully added, but the caption cannot be edited yet.

```
// ./CustomImage.ts
// @ts-ignore
import { Node, Plugin } from 'tiptap'
// @ts-ignore
import { nodeInputRule } from 'tiptap-commands'

const IMAGE_INPUT_REGEX = /!\[(.+|:?)\]\((\S+)(?:(?:\s+)["'](\S+)["'])?\)/

export default class CustomImage extends Node {
  get name () {
    return 'customImage'
  }

  get schema () {
    return {
      attrs: {
        src: {
          default: null
        },
        alt: {
          default: null
        },
        title: {
          default: null
        },
        caption: {
          default: null
        }
      },
      group: 'block',
      selectable: false,
      draggable: true,
      parseDOM: [
        {
          tag: 'figure'
        },
        [
          {
            tag: 'img[src]',
            getAttrs: (dom: any) => ({
              src: dom.getAttribute('src'),
              title: dom.getAttribute('title'),
              alt: dom.getAttribute('alt')
            })
          },
          {
            tag: 'figcaption'
          }
        ]
      ],
      toDOM: (node: any) => [
        'figure',
        [
          'img',
          {
            src: node.attrs.src,
            title: node.attrs.title,
            alt: node.attrs.alt
          }
        ],
        [
          'figcaption',
          {
            contenteditable: 'true'
          },
          node.attrs.caption
        ]
      ]
    }
  }

  commands ({ type }: any) {
    return (attrs: any) => (state: any, dispatch: any) => {
      const { selection } = state
      const position = selection.$cursor ? selection.$cursor.pos : selection.$to.pos
      const node = type.create(attrs)
      const transaction = state.tr.insert(position, node)
      dispatch(transaction)
    }
  }

  inputRules ({ type }: any) {
    return [
      nodeInputRule(IMAGE_INPUT_REGEX, type, (match: any) => {
        const [, alt, src, title] = match
        return {
          src,
          alt,
          title
        }
      })
    ]
  }

  get plugins () {
    return [
      new Plugin({
        props: {
          handleDOMEvents: {
            drop (view: any, event: any) {
              const hasFiles = event.dataTransfer &&
              event.dataTransfer.files &&
              event.dataTransfer.files.length

              if (!hasFiles) {
                return
              }

              const images = Array
                .from(event.dataTransfer.files)
                .filter((file: any) => (/image/i).test(file.type))

              if (images.length === 0) {
                return
              }

              event.preventDefault()

              const { schema } = view.state
              const coordinates = view.posAtCoords({ left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY })

              images.forEach((image: any) => {
                const reader = new FileReader()

                reader.onload = (readerEvent: any) => {
                  const node = schema.nodes.image.create({
                    src: readerEvent.target.result
                  })
                  const transaction = view.state.tr.insert(coordinates.pos, node)
                  view.dispatch(transaction)
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(image)
              })
            }
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a minimally working example with glitch or some other editor?

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: @kyw See below.

Comment: kyw, Sentient
Sorry for the late reply!
I am very happy if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a "hole" in the figure caption to make it editable. See https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#model.NodeSpec.toDOM. I implemented one of the solutions mentioned in the ProseMirror thread mentioned; however, the cursor can still enter text in between image and figurecaption. I would recommend using the last example with 3 schemas instead.

```js
  get schema() {
    return {
      content: "inline*",
      attrs: {src: {default: ""}, title: {default: ""}},
      group: 'block',
      draggable: true,
      isolating: true,
      parseDOM: [{
        tag: "figure",
        contentElement: "figcaption",
        getAttrs(dom) {
          let img = dom.querySelector("img")
          console.log(img, img.getAttribute('src'), img.getAttribute('alt'));
          return {src: img.getAttribute('src'), title: img.getAttribute('alt')}
        }
      }],
      toDOM: node => ["figure", ["img", node.attrs], ["figurecaption", 0]],
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!
This example is infinitely close to what I wanted to do. Thank you very much!

There is no value in the caption now, but do you know how to put the pre-specified value here? I want to continue editing.
I added a simple demo GIF animation as a link at the top of the above question.

Comment: @Mmz What do you mean by pre-specified value? Do you want to initialize the text in the figcaption to something?

Comment: Since the caption value is stored in the database in advance for each image, I want to set that value as the initial caption value for each image.
The initial caption value for each image is a character string that I entered appropriately as "captioncaption11111" in the GIF animation that was pasted at the top of the question. This is stored in the database as the initial caption for each image.
Does this description tell you what I want to do?

Comment: Yes. I think the schema above already does that. You just have to save the document as html or json, and use the prosemirror load from html or json methods.

Comment: If you don't have an initial document, then you can either 1. get it into a html or json format that prosemirror can use 2. create a method that initializes a figure node into the document, using the NodeType `create` method from here: https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#model.NodeType. See how it takes in attrs and content as arguments. In the example above, you'd pass in (src, title) as attrs and (caption) as content.

Comment: If you create three separate schemas for figure, image, and figcaption, as mentioned in `petcaption` example in the discuss Prosemirror thread you linked, then you would need to initialize three separate nodes, link them together into the parent figure node, and then insert that into the document.